# How <div> in jquery selector work?

Tags: jquery

I use `$('div')` to select all `<div>` tags from DOM.

But, when i accidentally used `$('<div>')` in chrome console, it returned `<div> </div>`.

I was wondering what is happening here, does this select `<div>` tag from existing DOM or it creates a new element in current DOM ?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('div')
```

- selects all div tags

```
$('<div>') or $('<div/>')
```

-will 'create' a div dom element but will not be added to HTML markup unless manipulated.